# Al aplicar lapply a una lista, no me funcionan los ggplot dentro de mi función

Tags: r, ggplot2

Llamo a las librerias que necesito,leo los archivos, creo el dataframe que necesito, lo limpio (quitarle 0 y NA), filtro las columnas que necesito y después divido el dataframe acorde a nombres comunes en ellas, y todo eso funciona:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)  
library(actuar) 
library(e1071) 
library(FAdist)
library(gld)
library(MonteCarlo)
library(snow)

archivos <- c("2014_1.csv",
              "2014_2.csv",
              "2014_3.csv",
              "2014_4.csv",
              "2015_1.csv",
              "2015_2.csv",
              "2015_3.csv",
              "2015_4.csv",
              "2016_1.csv",
              "2016_2.csv",
              "2016_3.csv",
              "2016_4.csv",
              "2017_1.csv",
              "2017_2.csv",
              "2017_3.csv",
              "2017_4.csv",
              "2018_1.csv",
              "2018_2.csv",
              "2018_3.csv",
              "2018_4.csv",
              "2019_1.csv")
lista_df <- lapply(archivos, function (x) read.table(x, sep=";",header=T))
df_unido <- reduce(rbind, lista_df) 

df_unido_n <- df_unido %>% 
    dplyr::select(NombreCentral,POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH,COMBUSTIBLE,CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON_MWH) %>%
    filter(POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH >0,!is.na(POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH) , CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON_MWH >0, !is.na(CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON_MWH))
    df_unido_n$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON = df_unido_n$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON_MWH * df_unido_n$POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH

lista_total= list()
for (i in 1:44){
    dfn=df_unido_n %>%
        filter(NombreCentral == nmb[i])
    lista_total[[i]]<-dfn
}
```

Todo dentro de la función funciona, lo evalué para algunos elementos de lista_total y corre sin ningún problema. Grafico para ver comportamiento de los datos (esta parte es la que falla), creo variables para aproximar funciones de distribución a los datos, vuelvo a graficar, pero esta vez con las distribuciones para ver como se ajustan a los datos (esta parte también falla) y finalmente veo que tan certero son mis aproximaciones (summary, gofstaty bootdist, este último es mas lento que el resto)

```
function.CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON<-function(var_list){
    ggplot(var_list, aes(x = CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + geom_density()
    ggplot(var_list, aes(var_list$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 20)
    ggplot(var_list, aes(var_list$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "point", size=1) + ggtitle("CDF GRAPHIC")
    ggplot(var_list, aes(x = CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=0.1, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(alpha=0.2, size=0.4) + ggtitle("DENSITY AND HISTOGRAM GRAPHIC")
    col_1=var_list$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON
    print(summary(col_1))
    plotdist(col_1, histo=TRUE, demp=TRUE)
    descdist(col_1)
    fw2_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "weibull")
    fw3_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "weibull3", start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1)) 
    fg_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "gamma")
    fln_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "lnorm")
    fex_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "exp")
    fgm_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "gumbel",start=list(scale=50, location=50))
    fn_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "norm")
    fll_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "llogis", start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1))
    fl_1 <- fitdist(col_1, "logis")

    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot.legend<-c("Weibull","Weibull3","lnorm","gamma","exp","gumbel","norm","llogis","logis")
    denscomp(list(fw2_1,fw3_1,fg_1,fln_1,fex_1,fgm_1,fn_1,fll_1,fl_1), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
    cdfcomp(list(fw2_1,fw3_1,fg_1,fln_1,fex_1,fgm_1,fn_1,fll_1,fl_1), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
    qqcomp(list(fw2_1,fw3_1,fg_1,fln_1,fex_1,fgm_1,fn_1,fll_1,fl_1), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))
    ppcomp(list(fw2_1,fw3_1,fg_1,fln_1,fex_1,fgm_1,fn_1,fll_1,fl_1), plotstyle = "ggplot",legendtext = c("weibull-2P", "weibull-3P", "gamma", "lognormal", "exponential", "gumbel", "normal", "loglogistic", "logistic"))

    print(summary(fw2_1))
    print(summary(fw3_1))
    print(summary(fg_1))
    print(summary(fln_1))
    print(summary(fex_1))
    print(summary(fgm_1))
    print(summary(fn_1))
    print(summary(fll_1))
    print(summary(fl_1))
    print(gofstat(fw2_1))
    print(gofstat(fw3_1))
    print(gofstat(fg_1))
    print(gofstat(fln_1))
    print(gofstat(fex_1))
    print(gofstat(fgm_1))
    print(gofstat(fn_1))
    print(gofstat(fll_1))
    print(gofstat(fl_1))
    print(bootdist(fw2_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fw3_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fg_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fln_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fex_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fgm_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fn_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fll_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
    print(bootdist(fl_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
}
```

Con lapply le aplico a lista_total (lista de 44 dataframes de distinta longitud cada uno)

```
col1t<-lapply(lista_total,function.CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)
```

No sé que hago mal, porfa ayuda estimables.
(Creo que hay esta parte de los datos)
structure(list(NombreCentral = structure(c(28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), .Label = c("ANDINA", "ANGAMOS", 
"ANTILHUE TG", "BOCAMINA ", "CANDELARIA", "CARDONES (EX TIERRA AMARILLA)", 
"CENTRAL ATACAMA", "CENTRAL ESPERANZA", "COLMITO", "CORONEL", 
"DIEGO DE ALMAGRO ", "EMELDA", "GUACOLDA", "HORCONES", "HUASCO", 
"IQUIQUE", "LAGUNA VERDE", "LOS PINOS", "LOS VIENTOS", "MEJILLONES", 
"NEHUENCO", "NORGENER", "QUINTERO ", "RENCA - NUEVA RENCA", "SAN FRANCISCO DE MOSTAZAL", 
"SAN ISIDRO I", "SAN ISIDRO II", "SAN LORENZO DE DIEGO DE ALMAGRO", 
"SANTA LIDIA", "SANTA MARÍA I", "TALTAL ", "TARAPACA", "TOCOPILLA", 
"VENTANA II", "VENTANA IV (EX CENTRAL CAMPICHE)", "VENTANAS I", 
"VENTANAS III", "YUNGAY (EX CAMPANARIO)", "EL SALVADOR", "LAUTARO-COMASA", 
"CENTRAL LOS GUINDOS", "CENTRAL TERMOELÉCTRICA COCHRANE", "CENTRAL KELAR", 
"SALAR", "TRES PUENTES"), class = "factor"), POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH = c(22.1200008392334, 
22.1200008392334, 22.1200008392334, 22.1200008392334, 22.1200008392334, 
9.85000038146973, 9.85000038146973, 9.85000038146973, 9.85000038146973, 
0.499000012874603, 1.47099995613098, 2.76300001144409, 4.68599987030029, 
4.56899976730347, 13.58899974823, 8.62199974060059, 2.1340000629425, 
6.85599994659424, 4.80499982833862, 4.56400012969971, 0.497000008821487, 
9.79899978637695, 26.0629997253418, 12.8699998855591, 26.5599994659424, 
29.5799999237061, 29.2199993133545, 28.8649997711182, 28.7199993133545, 
28.7199993133545, 11.3100004196167, 8.09000015258789, 2.74000000953674, 
11.9200000762939, 26.0499992370605, 26.2600002288818, 26.2849998474121, 
26.2600002288818, 26.2450008392334, 13.75, 1.61000001430511, 
0.194999992847443, 2.99000000953674, 20.6599998474121, 30, 30.4200000762939, 
30.5599994659424, 30.5, 31.7600002288818, 30.5), CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2 = c(0.455000013113022, 
0.446000009775162, 0.551999986171722, 0.528999984264374, 1.98399996757507, 
0.328999996185303, 0.319000005722046, 0.225999996066093, 0.363999992609024, 
0.0879999995231628, 0.279000014066696, 0.229000002145767, 0.356000006198883, 
0.10700000077486, 0.143999993801117, 0.108999997377396, 0.202999994158745, 
0.025000000372529, 0.546000003814697, 0.303000003099442, 0.250999987125397, 
0.796000003814697, 1.33299994468689, 1.00399994850159, 4.92899990081787, 
5.53499984741211, 5.42999982833862, 5.3730001449585, 5.36299991607666, 
5.34000015258789, 6.59600019454956, 1.37300002574921, 1.14900004863739, 
2.24300003051758, 4.69899988174438, 4.75600004196167, 4.77299976348877, 
4.76399993896484, 4.76800012588501, 4.5149998664856, 0.467999994754791, 
0.0710000023245811, 0.556999981403351, 3.59999990463257, 5.69999980926514, 
5.80200004577637, 5.82100009918213, 5.84299993515015, 6.04699993133545, 
5.7810001373291)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Lo que estás planteando requiere que hagamos un debug de tu código, cosa que es imposible hacer sin los datos ni los conocimiento mínimos de dominio. Te sugiero que reduzcas tu problema. Arma una función con una sola gráfica, la que falla y nada más, trata de reproducir el problema con un conjunto minímo de datos, comparte esos datos y código mínimos

Comment: Como les comparto los datos?, ese siempre es mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función `dput()` para compartir los datos y que sea posible reproducir el código, ya que no disponemos de los archivos **.csv** que utilizaste.

Por otro lado, me atrevo a especular que la razón por la cual `lapply` no está sirviendo, es consecuencia de que la función "`function.CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON`"  no está retornando algo útil para ser asignado.

Como la última operación realizada dentro de la función es:

```
print(bootdist(fl_1,bootmethod = "param",niter=51,silent = TRUE))
```

y no se utilizó `return()` para retornar algo específico en la última línea, eso trae como consecuencia que al querer hacer una asignación las cosas no salgan bien. La función retorna lo que sucede en la última línea , este caso un print.

**Una solución que se me ocurre sería ir creando distintos objetos, agruparlos en una lista y que la función retorne esa misma lista con todos los objetos que se fueron creando dentro de dicha función.**

Prueba reescribir algo como esto:

```
function.CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON <- function(var_list) {

    A     <- ggplot(var_list, aes(x = CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + geom_density()
    B     <- ggplot(var_list, aes(var_list$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 20)
    C     <- ggplot(var_list, aes(var_list$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "point", size=1) + ggtitle("CDF GRAPHIC")
    D     <- ggplot(var_list, aes(x = CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)) +  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=0.1, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(alpha=0.2, size=0.4) + ggtitle("DENSITY AND HISTOGRAM GRAPHIC")
    col_1 <- var_list$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON
    E     <- summary(col_1)

    RETORNAR <- list(A, B, C, D, E)
}
```

puedes ir expandiendo la función con las cosas que faltan utilizando la misma lógica de retornar una lista con todos los objetos creados dentro de la función.

Notar que asigné `summary(col_1)` a la variable `E` en vez de utilizar la función `print`.

Finalmente, cuando ejecutes:

```
col1t <- lapply(lista_total, function.CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON)
```

`colt1t` debería quedar como una lista de 44 listas que contienen gráficos y summaries.

Espero que a pesar de nos disponer de los datos utilizados pueda ayudar a resolver el problema.

Comment: Usé la función deput en la última linea, servirá?, y con lo otro me dio el siguiente error: Error in return(A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J) : 
  multi-argument returns are not permitted

Comment: Estimado Daniel, primero tienes que crear una lista con los elementos A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J que asumo son objetos de distinto tipo. Puedes crear la lista con el siguiente código: ```lista <- list(A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J)```. Finalmente en la última línea de la función agregas ```return(lista)```. El error "multi-argument returns are not permitted" se debe a que la función no deja retornar varias cosas a la vez, por eso primero es conveniente crear una lista con todos los objetos juntos. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Si, me di cuenta de mi error, muchas gracias

Comment: Se pudo ver la data con el deput que puse?

Comment: Para el código de la pregunta puedes utilizar por ejemplo: ```dput(lista_total[[1]])```. Que devuelve en la consola (el primero de los 44 dataframes que se encuentran en la lista) en un formato crudo para que lo puedas copiar y pegar. Si el data frame contiene muchas filas puedes cortarlo, es decir, incluir solo algunas. Por ejemplo, ```dput(lista_total[[1]][1:15, ])``` va a tener como output solamente 15 renglones de todo el dataframe . Saludos.

Comment: Estimado, ahí en el código al final lo añadí

Comment: @VichoDániel te anduvo lapply? saludos.

Comment: Si, pero me arrojo errores ya de otras cosas que no son del lapply